# Copy files (SCP) by shiny app

Tags: r, ubuntu, path, shiny, scp

I have 2 linux server. One is used as shiny server and the other for SQL database. I have a shiny app, which read some excel files and store the data into a sql database. I have created a folder also to copy all the excel files somewhere into my second server which is SQL server.

I know I can use the file.copy command to do so :

```
file.copy(infile$datapath, file.path("/srv/shiny-server/storage/", infile$name),recursive= TRUE)
```

This is working If I want to store them in shiny server. how should I modify this command if I want to store them on the other server (It has different IP/host addresses) ? It should be `scp` but how to do it via R ?

Comment: Have you tried calling `scp <source> <destination>` through `system()`?

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin, I have tried `system(paste0("sshpass -p 'password' scp /srv/shiny-server/storage/",infile$name," ali@1.1.1.1:/etc/mysql/storage"),wait = FALSE)
` inside shiny it doesn't work but in R itself it is working !